# Why do my game objects become invisible as soon as I attach the material to which this shader script is applied?

Tags: unity, shaders, fragment-shader, unity-shader-graph

I wrote a shader script that is an extension of the Sprite-Lit shader in previous Unity versions' standard assets in an attempt to feather the edges of a sprite using additive blending. Here is the script:

```
Shader "Unlit/Sprite-Lit-Add-Feathering"
{
    Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData] _MainTex("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [MaterialToggle] PixelSnap("Pixel snap", Float) = 0
        [PerRendererData] _AlphaTex("External Alpha", 2D) = "white" {}
        [PerRendererData] _AlphaTexST("External Alpha ST", 2D) = "white" {}

        // Gradient property for the feathering effect
        [PerRendererData] _Feathering("Feathering", 2D) = "white" {}
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        {
            "Queue"="Transparent"
            "IgnoreProjector"="True"
            "RenderType"="Transparent"
            "PreviewType"="Plane"
            "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
        }

        // Set the blend mode to "Blend One One" to enable additive blending
        Blend One One

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 3.0

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata_t
            {
                float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                float4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color    : COLOR;
                half2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            v2f vert(appdata_t IN, uniform fixed4 _Color)
            {
                v2f OUT;
                OUT.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(IN.vertex);
                OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
                OUT.color = IN.color * _Color;
                #ifdef PIXELSNAP_ON
                OUT.vertex = UnityPixelSnap (OUT.vertex);
                #endif

                return OUT;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f IN, uniform sampler2D _MainTex, uniform sampler2D _Feathering) : SV_Target
            {
                // Sample the texture and multiply it by the vertex color
                fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) * IN.color;

                // Sample the feathering gradient to get the feathering factor
                float featheringFactor = tex2D(_Feathering, IN.texcoord).r;

                // Multiply the color by the feathering factor to achieve the feathering effect
                c *= featheringFactor;

                // Return the resulting color
                return c;
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

However, as soon as I attach the material to which this script is applied to to any 2d sprite game object, the game object simply becomes invisible in both scene view and game view. Why is this the case, and what should I modify in order to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you show us the textures/colours you're using for each property, and what the background behind the sprite looks like in your scene?

Answer (score 0):

my guess is your vertex colors are all zero - try changing `COLOR` in your vertex structs to `COLOR0`

If that doesn't work, maybe try working off [this example](https://gist.github.com/jhorikawa/7a236ae0b801bf2aca2d8a3038b9bf40) for basic vertex lighting visualization

Comment: Thank you so much! However, I changed all the vertex structs to COLOR0 and the sprites still turn invisible when the material with the shader script is applied:( I really can't figure out what the issue is:(

Comment: hmm what happens if you comment out where you apply the vertex color?